# Why report not showing anymore after a converter to highlight some keywords is added?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I added the converter that is suppose to highlight some key words in the report but now the report doesn't show at all. If I deleted the converter from the xaml code the report will show. The code indicates that it will just return the original object if no keywords are found. Don't know what I did wrong.

xaml:

```
 <local:AdvisoryReportView x:Name="_advisoryReportView" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                               DataContext="{Binding AdvisoryViewModels, Converter={StaticResource highlightKeywordsConverter}}"/>
```

C#

```
public class HighlightKeywordsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string returnText = string.Empty; // "Nothing Selected";
        string input = null;
        string replacementText = null;
        string replacePattern = null;
        string[] keyWords = new string[]
        {
                "test1",
                "test2",
                "test3",
        };
        if (value != null && !value.ToString().Contains("DependencyProperty.UnsetValue"))
            input = value.ToString();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    if (input.Contains(keyWords[i]))
                    {
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                replacementText = String.Format(
                                    "<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: Blue\">{0}</FONT>", "$1");
                                replacePattern = @"(?![^<>]*>)(" + keyWords[i] + ")";
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                replacementText = String.Format(
                                    "<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: Beige\">{0}</FONT>", "$1");
                                replacePattern = @"(?![^<>]*>)(" + keyWords[i] + ")";
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                replacementText = String.Format(
                                    "<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: Azure\">{0}</FONT>", "$1");
                                replacePattern = @"(?![^<>]*>)(" + keyWords[i] + ")";
                                break;                                                                                                                             
                        } //end of switch

                        returnText = Regex.Replace(input,
                                                   replacePattern,
                                                   replacementText,
                                                   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    } //end of if
                    else return input;
                }//end of for
            } //end of if
            else
            {
                  // Otherwise, just send back the original text, or an 
                  // empty string if we did not get anything.
                  returnText = input;
            }


        return returnText;
    } //end of Convert

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

} //end of class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your converter. The primary cause of your problem is certainly the return statement inside the for loop when a keyword was not found, as it stops looking for any remaining keywords. And always using the `input` variable as first parameter to the `Replace` method results in ignoring any previously made replacements.

I guess this Convert method is all you need:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var returnText = value as string;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnText))
    {
        var keywords = new string[]
        {
            "test1",
            "test2",
            "test3",
        };

        var replacements = new string[]
        {
            "<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: Blue\">$1</FONT>",
            "<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: Beige\">$1</FONT>",
            "<FONT style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: Azure\">$1</FONT>"
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Length; i++)
        {
            var replacePattern = @"(?![^<>]*>)(" + keywords[i] + ")";

            returnText = Regex.Replace(returnText,
                                       replacePattern,
                                       replacements[i],
                                       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
    }

    return returnText;
}
```